# How to modify an attribute of a certain item in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called `Category` which contains categories that are used to categorise products. One of the categories is called `Experiences`. On a specific query, I'd like to modify it from `Experiences` to `Experiences *` for display purposes.

I have tried to do this via a map, but am getting a blank value for `Experiences`.

This is my code:

```
  def self.with_exp_star
    Category.all.map { |element|
      if element.name == "Experiences"
        element.name = "Experiences *"
      else
        element
      end
      }
  end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: As a side point, what is the purpose of adding an asterisk to the end of names in your database? It is very unusual to get an app to read meaning in to a name field. There may be a simpler way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hey @AJFaraday as above its purely for display purposes, I am not looking to modify the data itself.

Comment: I'll reiterate, what are the display purposes? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: It's already solved mate...

Comment: I'm a little concerned that this feels like a nonsense requirement. As though you're fixing something that occurred as a stop-gap solution to another issue, where it may make more sense to address the initial issue than the fix. Either way, you seem happy with it. Take care, now.

Comment: I just want to display my list of categories with one of them having an * so I can provide some context to the user.. that is all. Thanks for your input and attention. It's appreciated.. think we're all good though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when `element.name == "Experiences"` you are pushing `element.name` to the result array, but `element` object otherwise, while you should return `element` in both ways:

```
Category.all.map { |element|
  element.name += ' *' if element.name == 'Experiences'
  element
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails 3 upwards you can chain a query with update_all, like so:

```
Categories.where(:name => "Experiences).update_all(:name => "Experiences *")
```

Comment: Correct @suslov, smart guy!

Comment: Then I really do need some context, conditionally concatenation a symbol to a name is a very unusual goal.